Verifying signature of private_key_jwt in spring authorization server
Im trying to implement private_key_jwt client authentication in spring authorization server (oauth2). But im having trouble implementing signature verification. From what i see i have to specify "JwkSetUri", since this part of code is throwing an exception
if (jwsAlgorithm instanceof SignatureAlgorithm) {
    clientSecret = registeredClient.getClientSettings().getJwkSetUrl(); //This is null
    if (!StringUtils.hasText(clientSecret)) {
        oauth2Error = new OAuth2Error("invalid_client", "Failed to find a Signature Verifier for Client: '" + registeredClient.getId() + "'. Check to ensure you have configured the JWK Set URL.", "https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7523#section-3");
        throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(oauth2Error);
    } else {
        return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(clientSecret).jwsAlgorithm((SignatureAlgorithm)jwsAlgorithm).restOperations(restTemplate).build();
    }

So i have 2 questions. Is client supposed to expose this JwkUri endpoint so authorization server can fetch public key from it? And if so, can i maybe do it without exposing an endpoint and somehow load the key from file?
I tried to find a solution, but seems like there is only one jwt decoder implemented by spring authorization server and its requiring a jwk-uri. Coding totaly seperate decoder seems like overkill.
